# Calling MouseLeave chartJs Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, frontend

I have the code below:

**Angular component html**

```
<canvas myChart>
   [dataset] = "dataVariable"
   [labels] = "labelVariable"
   (chartHover) = "chartHover($event)"
</canvas>
```

**Component.ts**

```
public chartHover(e: any){
   //Perform operations
}
```

I'm actually calling a custom pop-up whenever I hover over an element. The problem is I haven't found a way to trigger the mouseleave event to make the component disappear.

I've tried this:

```
(chartMouseLeave) = "funct()"
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the event to [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) event of the canvas.

```
<canvas myChart>
   [dataset] = "dataVariable"
   [labels] = "labelVariable"
   (chartHover) = "chartHover($event)"
   (mouseout) = "mouseOut($event)"
</canvas>
```

Component

```
public mouseOut(event: any){
   // set pop up open flag to false
}
```

Comment: Though (mouseOut) seemed to work. The problem is that it only works when I hover outside of the graph. I wanted it to call the function as soon as I hover my mouse outside of the bar(becuase I'm using a bargraph) to make it behavie like the tooltip